# Postgres: check constraint только буквы

Tags: регулярные-выражения, postgresql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать CHECK для column при создании таблицы так, чтобы там могли быть только англ буквы (заглавные и строчные)?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS elections.voters
(
voter_id serial4,
fname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL CHECK (fname ~ ‘^[A-Z].*$)
```

`~ ‘^[A-Z].*$)` - неверное решение.
Как правильно написать? Спасибо!

Comment: Правильно - поле "не не-буква". Ну и баланс кавычек..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема и с синтаксисом и с кавычками, да и регулярное выражение какое-то не очень корректное.

Вот такой вариант рабочий

```sql
fname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL CHECK (fname ~* '^[A-Z]*$')
```

В регулярном выражении указывается что оно может содержать только буквы от **A** до **Z**. Указание  **~*** говорит о том что сравнение нужно делать без учета регистра букв. Т.е. проверку будут проходить символы в верхнем и нижнем регистре.

Если нужно добавить еще какие-то символы в разрешеные - то можно просто изменить регулярное выражение.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS elections.voters (
  voter_id serial4,
  fname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL CHECK (fname !~ '[^A-Z]')
  );
```

Если надо без учёта регистра - то соответственно `!~*`.